# Propagator notation

Tags: packages, simplewick

How can I use the following kind of notation in LaTeX?[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is probably to use the package [`simpler-wick`](https://ctan.org/pkg/simpler-wick). Here's an example with an output similar to your image.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{simpler-wick}
\begin{document}
\[
\wick{
  +\c1 \phi_1 \c1 \phi_2 \c1 \phi_3 \c1 \phi_4 
  +\c1 \phi_1 \c2 \phi_2 \c1 \phi_3 \c2 \phi_4 
  +\c2 \phi_1 \c1 \phi_2 \c1 \phi_3 \c2 \phi_4
}
\]
\end{document}
```

If you want an alternative, there is also the package [`simplewick`](https://ctan.org/pkg/simplewick).